# NestJS dependencies of dependencies have to be declared

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm having an issue with NestJS's dependencies-of-dependencies not being resolved automatically:

1. I have an AWSModule which is a very simple link to Amazon AWS with no dependencies except the ConfigService:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [ConfigService, AwsService],
    exports: [AwsService],
})
export class AwsModule {}
```

2. I use the above inside my AuthModule:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        AwsModule,
    ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, AwsService],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

So far so good, the above works perfectly fine.

Now the trouble comes in when I want to use AuthService somewhere else:

3. I have a UserModule that needs to import an AuthModule:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        AuthModule,
    ],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService, AuthService, /*** BREAKS WITHOUT THIS: ***/ AwsService],
    exports: [SequelizeModule],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

If I dont include the AwsService here which is only used by AuthModule, it breaks.

**Why does my UserModule need to know about the internal dependencies of the AuthModule?** If I use the AuthModule somewhere else in my program I dont want to have to repeatedly import all the dependencies of the AuthModule whereever it is used. Nest should figure out how to resolve these dependencies-of-dependencies?

In my root ApplicationModule, I am importing ALL modules declared:

```
@Module({
    imports: [

        //.env File Configuration Support:
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            isGlobal: true,
        }),

        ...

        //App Modules:
        AwsModule,
        AuthModule,
        UserModule,

    ],
    providers: [AppService],
    controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out.

the `providers` of a module are NOT imports necessary for constructor-based injection as I assumed from the documentation.

They seem to be classes that will be instantiated by the module and possibly exported (if they also appear in the `exports` array).

I removed all the external classes from my `providers` array and only left the direct classes of each module and it works!

I feel like this little aspect of NestJS wasnt super clear in the documentation. I re-read the section on Providers for the 3rd time and I didnt see anywhere explaining the exact use/requirements of the `providers` array.

Auth Module:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        SequelizeModule.forFeature([User]),
        AwsModule,
    ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService /** this is the only required provider, imports are injected just fine **/],
    exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

User Module

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        SequelizeModule.forFeature([User]),
        AuthModule,
    ],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService /** this is the only required provider, imports are injected just fine **/],
    exports: [SequelizeModule],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're registering the `AwsService` provider multiple times. No need to that for `UserModule` because it's importing the `AwsModule` -- which has the `AwsService` in their `exports` array. This is pretty basic stuff on Nestjs modules.

So remove the `AwsService` from `UserModule` and you should be fine, I guess.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem. I remove the AwsModule from UserModule and I get `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (UserRepository, JwtService, ConfigService, ?). Please make sure that the argument AwsService at index [3] is available in the UserModule context.`